# How to insert table view cells from a separate view?

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm pretty new to swift so bear with me.

I'm trying to make an app where the user can make a grocery list. I have a table view with a custom cell with a few sample cells. I have a button that brings up a new view where the user can enter the items, price and amount of items. There is a button that i would like to update the table with the new item. I can't seem to get it to update the table. Please help.

Here is the code i have:

```
import UIKit


var list = ["Chips", "Milk", "Eggs", "Meat"]
var price = [3.99 , 4.99 , 5.99, 12.99]
var amount = [1 , 1 , 12 , 1 ]
var note = ["Need some cheetos!", "Chocolate or vanilla?", "" , "I LOVE RIBEYES!!!"]

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var listTableView: UITableView!

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell 

        cell.itemName.text = list[indexPath.row]

    /*  cell.itemNote.text = note[indexPath.row]

        let priceString = "$\(price[indexPath.row])"
        cell.itemPrice.text = priceString

        let amountString = "\(amount[indexPath.row])"
        cell.itemAmount.text = amountString
    */

        return cell
    }

    func insert() {
        list.append("test")

        let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: list.count - 1, inSection: 0)

        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertionIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
```

And the second class.

```
class AddItemViewController: UIViewController {

    var listView: ListTableViewController?

    var checkPrice : Double = 0
    var checkAmount : Int = 1  

    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameTextbox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemPriceTextbox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemAmountTextbox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemNoteTextbox: UITextField!
    @IBAction func AddItemButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Checks if price is a valid number
    if (Double(itemPriceTextbox.text!) != nil){

        checkPrice = Double(itemPriceTextbox.text!)!

        print(checkPrice)
    } else {
        checkPrice = 0
        print("ERROR: Didn't enter a number \(checkPrice)")

    }

    // Checks if amount is a valid number
    if (Int(itemAmountTextbox.text!) != nil){

        checkAmount = Int(itemAmountTextbox.text!)!
        print(checkAmount)

    } else {
        checkAmount = 1
        print("ERROR: Didn't enter a number \(checkAmount)")

    }

    //Updates the inforamtion in arrays
    list.append(itemNameTextbox.text!)
    price.append(checkPrice)
    amount.append(checkAmount)
    note.append(itemNoteTextbox.text!)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you call `list.append(_)`, `price.append()`, `amount.append()` etc. instead of `listView?.list.append()`, `listView?.price.append()` etc. in your @IBAction on `AddItemsViewController`?

Comment: i dont think so, when i add text to the fields the arrays seem to update correctly when the button is pressed, im just having a hard time updating the tableview

Comment: After those list.append(), price.append() method calls, you need to call listView?.listTableView.reloadData() somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think how I would go about doing this is as follows

- AddItemViewController - Link it to core data and the data that the user adds should be added into a core data table
- Also I am not sure in your code I do not see a link to AddItemViewController. Can you explain more as to how you are transitioning from one view controller to another?
- In your ListTableViewController you should retrieve the data from the core data table and showcase in the table view.

Hope this is helpful. Please let me know if you require any clarification and good luck in solving the solution